# Can't read file using File.ReadAllLines

Tags: c#, .net, loops, for-loop, file.readalllines

I am trying to make a button check each line of the file in `openFileDialog1.FileName` and if it contains one of the strings, "LCD" or "laser" and "on" on the same line, or if it contains "laser" and "off" on the same line and the string ".end" and then do something.

I am new to C# (started this week) and that not a native English speaker either.

my goal is to make my Arduino Robot arm (my first build so its very simple) somewhat programmable, just to control the LCD and turn the laser on or off (so far).

BTW this is just the Simulator so that's why it never sends any serial data.

Below is a snippet of the code where the problem is, the problem is that when i "Run" the code in the simulator it seems to be checking all the lines at once because in the code it checks, which is

```
LCD = hello  
laser = on  
LCD = 000  
laser = off
```

it only sets the LCD to 000, i checked the laser = on code alone before and it didn't work  in there but when i tried it in `private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` it worked perfectly , so bottom line The last LCD command in each code works and the laser code never works.

also i want to have every line represent 1 second, so each line will take one second before it continues on the next line.

the `timer1` interval is 1000 (one second)

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int lineNumber = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.TextLength);


        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber; i++)
            {
                if (lines[i].Contains("LCD"))
                {
                    label1.Text = lines[i].Remove(0, 6);
                }
                if (lines[i].Contains("laser") && lines[i].Contains("On"))
                {
                    pictureBox4.Show();
                }
                if (lines[i].Contains("laser") && lines[i].Contains("Off"))
                {
                    pictureBox4.Hide();
                }
                if (lines[i].Contains(".end"))
                {
                    button2.PerformClick();
                } 

            } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Form3", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have recognized line breaks in your file?  Put a break point after you read in the lines and you can hover your mouse over `lines` to see its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you want to put the code that does the `File.ReadAllLines()` outside of your code that gets called once a second `timer1_Tick()`.  You're reading the entire file every time timer tick, when what you really want to do is just process one line of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (i feel pretty stupid now), but if i put it outside the timer function i get an error saying that "the name lines does not exist in the current context" could you be so kind to tell me how to do it. thanks in advance

Comment: @olleolofsson - don't fell that way - everyone make mistakes.  I'll work on expanding my answer, but that won't be until tomorrow.

Comment: there is no  need, i solved it and now it runs perfectly thanks for all the help :D